# How to change WooCommerce checkout url?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Ok, it's known

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_checkout_url', 
    function ( $checkout_url ) {
        return '/checkout2/';
    }, 300);
```

and I get to /checkout2 after pressing "Add to cart" button. But there's a 404!

How to make WC process this new url as checkout? I should do it dynamically, depending on the source of the traffic. There actually will be a number of urls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need an actual page with the checkout shortcode inside I believe, Woocommerce won't generate pages that don't exist just be filtering it's checkout url.

You seem to be changing the url successfully but the url you're changing to doesn't exist.